# Where should restricting IP address be handled?

Tags: security, reverse-proxy

We run a reverse proxy in front of our application tier and I'm wondering where the "best practice" place for handling the IP restriction is.

Currently, we use the application security to restrict access to specific resources by IP address but this has caused some issues when we moved to running behind a reverse proxy. It's quite easy to configure the allow/deny rules at the proxy instead of the application but since we run multiple applications behind the proxy, making modifications to the config there has the potential to affect other application (not a huge danger, but still present).

Is it better to do the filter further up the chain or closer to the application?

Are there any gotchas, like what we've encountered by doing application restriction and adding a reverse proxy where all the requests "come from" the proxy, forcing us to use a header to find the "real" IP address.

Comment: Hows is your application hosted? Own Servers? Co-lo? Rackspace? At my last company we used Rackspace and just sent a request to them to restrict IPs at the network level.

Comment: Currently, we're hosted in a co-location. We're in the process of moving to Amazon's EC2 environment. We're not looking to do IP restriction at the network level as sometimes, only certain resources need to be restricted by IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We filter as early as possible and keep it away from the application; these sort of things are better managed by network operations. The reason being is that app developers or maintainers are not always in on the loop when changing ip addresses and the network ops people are usually the first to know. Also network type tools are usually better at providing / restricting access that software level tools.

Answer (score 2):

I would never restrict by IP address. Restrictions like that are the job of a security layer, not of the Network layer, which is where IP addresses live. I rarely find value in having an Application restrict the implementation of the Network.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of resources that need to be restricted by IP. If parts of the application need to be restricted via IP then the application should be handling it. If the entire application needs to be blocked then you should be further up the chain.

The general rule is to restrict as early as possible without compromising any audit systems you have in place (it is almost always a good idea to know when people try to break your security system).

Answer (score 0):

I restrict by IP addresses as early as possible - this eliminates unnecessary traffic in the following layers or subnetworks. So my advice is similar to u07ch's do it as early as possible.